# Potential difference across the terminals of a battery with internal resistance

Tags: electrical-resistance, batteries

The potential difference across the terminals of a battery with resistance is equal to the emf when there is no current.But when there is a current there the potential difference decreases or increases depending on the direction of the current.How does this change in voltage occur.Does the charge density at the plates of the battery change? Or, something else happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General Ohm's law (based on Ohm's experiments with voltaic piles and thermocouple) implies that current $I$ in a circuit with a battery and a resistor $R$ is

$$
I = \frac{\mathscr{E}}{R+R_i},
$$

where $\mathscr{E}$ is electromotive force of the battery, and $R_i$ is additional resistance due to the battery, called *internal resistance*. (The same follows from Kirchhoff's second circuital law, which is a generalization of Ohm's law).

That is, the battery also poses some resistance to current when it flows in the battery.

Let's write down KVL for this circuit:

$$
RI + U_{battery} = 0,
$$

where $U_{battery}$ is potential drop on the battery (a negative number, since inside battery, potential increases in direction of current).

Combining the last two equations, we get

$$
|U_{battery}| = RI = \frac{R}{R+R_i} \mathscr{E}.
$$

Thus, magnitude of $U_{battery}$ is always less than $\mathscr{E}$, due to internal resistance $R_i$ being non-zero.

When the battery is disconnected from the circuit, this can be analyzed as if it was in another circuit with very high $R$, many times higher than $R_i$. For such $R$, $R_i$ can be neglected, as

$$
\lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{R}{R+R_i} = 1
$$
and thus magnitude of battery's potential difference becomes $\mathscr{E}$.

> How does this change in voltage occur.Does the charge density at the plates of the battery change? Or, something else happens?

Yes, potential difference between terminals of the battery is due to presence of separated charges on the battery terminals (and other charged objects nearby). Lowering of the potential difference after $R$ is lowered (after battery is connected to a circuit with resistor of small resistance) means there is less charge on the terminals.

Answer (score 0):

You have a current through the batterie, so $U=R_i*I+R_a*I$ so U of the Batterie is $U=R_i*I$